# 3D Model not loading on android device

Tags: android, three.js, 3d-model

I have a page on my(very very recent only 2days old) website that contains a 3D model.  The model was made in Blender, and was exported in the .glb format using glTF-Blender-IO by the KhronosGroup.  It is uploaded with the THREE.GLTFLoader.  Everything works perfectly fine on desktop and on iOS devices, however not on Android devices.  The model simply does not show up.  The error I get reads as follows:

```
Three.WebGlShader: Shader couldn't compile
Three.WebGlProgram: shader error:1282 35715 false
gl.getProgramInfoLog invalid shaders WARNING:0:1:'GL_OES_standard_derivatives':extension is not supported
```

```js
'use strict';  

window.onload = function() {
 main();
}

function main() {
 var canvas = document.querySelector('#canvasExpo58');
 
 var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({canvas, antialias:true, alpha:true}); 
 var fov = 45;
 var aspect = window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight;
 var near = 1;
 var far = 1000;
 var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(fov, aspect, near, far);
 camera.position.set(10, 2, 5);    //Zou moeten de initiële positie van de camera zijn bij opstarten: dus wat je als eerste ziet vooraleer je de muis beweegt
 
 var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, canvas);
 controls.target.set(10, 25, 10);   
 controls.update();
 
 var scene = new THREE.Scene();
 scene.background = renderer.setClearColor(0x000000, 0);    //Deze geeft, samen met de alpha:true in de WebGLRenderer, een transparante achtergrond
 
 
 {
 var light1 = new THREE.DirectionalLight(new THREE.Color(0xFFFFFF), 0.8);
 light1.position.set(-5, -5, 25);
 scene.add(light1);
 scene.add(light1.target);   
 }
 
 {
 var light2 = new THREE.DirectionalLight(new THREE.Color(0xFFFFFF), 1);
 light2.position.set(-40, -10, 4);
 scene.add(light2);
 scene.add(light2.target);   
 }
 {
 var light3 = new THREE.AmbientLight(new THREE.Color(0xCBC9D3), 0.9);
 scene.add(light3);
 scene.add(light3.target);    
 }
 

 
 {
  var loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();
  loader.load(
   'images/Dressoir.glb',
   (gltf) => {
    var root = gltf.scene;
    scene.add(root);
    
    var box = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(root);
    var boxSize = box.getSize(new THREE.Vector3()).length();
    var boxCenter = box.getCenter(new THREE.Vector3());
    
    //frameArea(boxSize * 0.5, boxSize, boxCenter, camera);
    
    controls.maxDistance = boxSize * 10;
    controls.target.copy(boxCenter);
    controls.update();
   }
  );
 }
 
 function resizeRendererToDisplaySize(renderer) {
  var canvas = renderer.domElement;
  var width = canvas.clientWidth;
  var height = canvas.clientHeight;
  var needResize = canvas.width !== width || canvas.height !== height;
  if (needResize) {
   renderer.setSize(width, height, false);
  }
  return needResize;
 }
 
 function render() {
  if (resizeRendererToDisplaySize(renderer)) {
   var canvas = renderer.domElement;
   camera.aspect = canvas.clientWidth/canvas.clientHeight;
   camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
  }
  
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
  
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
 }
 
 requestAnimationFrame(render);
 
}
```

[**Webpage of the Live Server**](https://equinoxwebdesign.be/expo58.html)

I have tried searching the web for an answer, but found nothing relevant.

Comment: How old is your Android device and which version of Android are you running? The mentioned WebGL extension `GL_OES_standard_derivatives` is required for `three.js` PBR material since `R112`. Older devices might have problems in supporting this extension.

Comment: I am using the LG K8 4G phone. Model number  LG K350n. The Android version is 6.0.  However, when running tests on the LambdaTest cross-browsertool I get the same error on other devices, such as the Samsung Galaxy note 10plus.

Comment: I can't reproduce this on a Pixel 1 (Android 10). Can you please try it with `R111`?

Comment: Hello Mugen87. I did as you suggested and installed R112 for my code.  Eventually nothing happened, however, when I updated the Chrome browser on my phone to the newest version, everything started to work perfectly.  Could it be that an outdated browser was (part of) the problem? Anyway, thank you very much for your assistance and the swift response.

Comment: Yes, an outdated browser or an outdated GPU driver could be responsible for this issue.